# Send email on changing line item field value

Tags: commerce

I have a custom list field on the product line item type, which is for the ability to set seperate shipping statuses for each product in one order.

When the store admin updates this list field on a line item, the site will need to send out an email to the customer.

Is there a nice way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches I can think of.

1. Use a hook to alter the update function to send an email out based on your conditions.

   Add JS to handle the change via a custom AJAX call.

   Create a cron job that monitors changes in the database and emails out messages when changes are picked up.

The first two options are your best and from those, depending on skill level, I would choose one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please expand on the first one? Whick hook are you thinking? I tried to write a form alter to the edit form, but I couldn't dpm() the variables (even though the custom submit handler was firing) or send the variable contents as watchdog message. I tried to look at field update hooks but none of them seemed to be working (no variable contents printed out while dpm-ing them)

Comment: I am willing to dig a bit for you. Can you please post your code try's in your question and elaborate a bit on each?